# Can't get single value after iteration on array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I use this code to iterate on the JavaScript objects array and return value:

```
this.selectedClient = _.forEach(self.clients, function (client) {
    if (client.IdentityNumber == -1) {
        return client;
    }
}) 

this.clients=[{firstName:"Tywin", lastName:"Lannister", age:46, IdentityNumber:2},
              {firstName:"Arya", lastName:"Starck", age:46, IdentityNumber:-1},
              {firstName:"John", lastName:"Snow", age:46, IdentityNumber:12},
              {firstName:"Robb", lastName:"Starck", age:46, IdentityNumber:24}];
```

But after iteration is done I expect that `selectedClient` veriable will get single item:

```
{firstName:"Arya", lastName:"Starck", age:46, IdentityNumber:-1}
```

But instead `selectedClient` veriable get all items in clients variable.

Any idea why I can't get single value after iteration on `clients` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `return` data from `forEach`.

Copying from the Lodash Docs for [`forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach)

> Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

Use [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs#find).

```
var selectedClient = _.find(clients, function (client) {
    if (client.IdentityNumber == -1) {
        return client;
    }
});
```

You can also use shorter syntax with Object as second parameter.

```
_.find(clients, {IdentityNumber: -1});
```

```js
var clients = [{
    firstName: "Tywin",
    lastName: "Lannister",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: 2
}, {
    firstName: "Arya",
    lastName: "Starck",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: -1
}, {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Snow",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: 12
}, {
    firstName: "Robb",
    lastName: "Starck",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: 24
}];


var selectedClient = _.find(clients, {IdentityNumber: -1});

console.log(selectedClient);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

For Vanilla Lovers, use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
clients.find(c => c.IdentityNumber === -1)
```

```js
var clients = [{
    firstName: "Tywin",
    lastName: "Lannister",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: 2
}, {
    firstName: "Arya",
    lastName: "Starck",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: -1
}, {
    firstName: "Robb",
    lastName: "Starck",
    age: 46,
    IdentityNumber: 24
}];

var selectedClient = clients.find(c => c.IdentityNumber === -1);
console.log(selectedClient);
```

Comment: what if I want to return a single property from client object for example Id?

Comment: @Michael `_.find(clients, {IdentityNumber: -1}) || {}.id`

Comment: could you please give brief explanation of code above?

Comment: this row _.find(clients, {IdentityNumber: -1}) || {}.id   returns all object but not property

Comment: after some research I modify your vanilla  code and I got desired result:  

`_.result(_.find(self.clients, { IdentityNumber: -1 }), 'Id')`;